# Disable specific rows in a SlickGrid table

Tags: slickgrid

This is how my table looks:

- a checkBox column
- a name column

The table contains 5 rows.

What I want to achieve is to make the last two rows of the table unselectable (the respective checkboxes in the checkBox column should also disappear).

I managed to do this with jQuery after the table was rendered. Does the SlickGrid table allow me to perform the above mentioned scenario?

Comment: I would think so - how are you rendering the checkbox column? Are you using the checkbox selector plugin - or a column formatter?

Comment: I use something like this: new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn()

Answer (score 3):

You can add a function for returning getItemMetadata() which is demonstrated in this [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html).

Here's a simplified version:

```
function getItemMetaData(row){

    if (row >= view.getLength() - 2){ //only on last two rows.
        return { selectable: false };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

var view = new Slick.Data.DataView();
view.getItemMetadata = getItemMetaData;
var grid = new Slick.Grid(selector, view, cols, opts);
```

This method is then called in `canCellBeSelected` at line 2944 in [`slick.grid.js`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/6e30827621f918c19db71644f6ef237d45805360/slick.grid.js)

Comment: Note this doesn't address the secondary question about the checkboxes.